# Can't read input file ERROR

Tags: java, file, embedded-resource, javax.imageio

I have a problem with the `File(String)` constructor.
It gives me `Can't read input file` Exception.
My JFrame is in the package `view`, and the images (files) are in `images`

```
/view
   /MyJFrame.java
/images
   /MyImage.jpe
```

so I want to import `MyImages.jpe` like this

```
Image img = ImageIO.read(new File("/src/images/MyImage.jpe"));
```

I want to make it worked in all the PCs, that's why I didn,t put absolute path. Please someone help here.

Comment: `/src/images/MyImage.jpe` Is it just because of the example you didn't surround it with double quotes?

Comment: yeah i'm sorry, of course it's with double quotes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How are you planning on deploying this? I suspect you'll want to put your whole application into a jar file... or at least on the classpath. At that point, assuming you have `/images` as a root within your classpath, you can do something like:

```
Image img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/images/MyImage.jpe"));
```

The problem at the moment is that you are providing an absolute filename, even though you really want a relative one... and at the point where the images are in a jar file, it wouldn't work anyway as they wouldn't be separate files.

Answer (score 1):

**Try to put your images folder right into your project folder:**

```
Image img = ImageIO.read(new File("/images/MyImage.jpg"));
```